# C# Get specific Date in ToInt64(milliseconds)

Tags: c#, datetime

I just cannot figure this out....Damnit!  Please see the calling method in the second code snippet.  You'll see a commented out line that reads **//_time = time.ToUTCString();**  Go to the first code snippet to see the method **ToUTCString()**.  You can see that it takes the datetime, converts it to Universal Time and subtracts the UnixEpoch to get the TotalSeconds.  Then it converts that value to Int64() and finally to a string.  I tried calling the methos ToLocalString but that's changing the date as well.

The date that I pass in is the date that I want to be converted to Int64 and eventually to a string.  The datetime I pass in.  Not changed.

I don't want to change the date that is passed in.  I always pass in the date starting with 12:00:00AM (or 00:00:00) and that is the time I always want.  **Both of these methods change the date and or time**.  The date I pass in is **06/01/2017 12:00:00AM** but sometimes it gets changed to **05/31/2017 04:00:00** or it keeps the date but the time is wrong.  Dark Sky requires the date to be a value of Convert.ToInt64(milliseconds) and then converted to a string.

Does anybody know how to get the exact date and time that is passed in converted to Int64 using milliseconds?

I have the following Extensions class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this Int64 _input)
    {
        return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(_input);
    }

    public static string ToLocalString(this DateTime _input)
    {
        // _input = {6/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
        var milliseconds = _input.ToLocalTime().Subtract(UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
        return Convert.ToInt64(milliseconds).ToString();
        // I want to get the milliseconds for {6/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}
        // I don't want the date or time to change
    }

    public static string ToUTCString(this DateTime _input)
    {
        // _input = {6/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
        var milliseconds = _input.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
        return Convert.ToInt64(milliseconds).ToString();
        // I want to get the milliseconds for {6/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}
        // I don't want the date or time to change
    }
}
```

This is the calling method:

```
    public ForecastIORequest(string apiKey, float latF, float longF, DateTime time, Unit unit, Language? lang = null, Extend[] extend = null, Exclude[] exclude = null)
    {
        _apiKey      = apiKey;
        _latitude    = latF.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        _longitude   = longF.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //_time      = time.ToUTCString();
        _time        = time.ToLocalString();
        //DateTime t = _time.
        _unit        = Enum.GetName(typeof(Unit), unit);
        _extend      = (extend != null) ? RequestHelpers.FormatExtendString(extend) : "";
        _exclude     = (exclude != null) ? RequestHelpers.FormatExcludeString(exclude) : "";
        _lang        = (lang != null) ? RequestHelpers.FormatLanguageEnum(lang) : Language.en.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want UTC, then don't set `DateTimeKind.UTC`.

Comment: I need a method similar to those in the first snippet that I can send in my datetime and return it in that same format.  Convert.ToInt64(milliseconds).ToString()

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is anymore. Please post a clear question stating what exactly you're trying to achieve and what's not working.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you included actual input with expected output and current output. I also did not read which methods were giving you a problem, all 3 seem interdependent and thus could have their own issue/behavior (there is likely not a common bug).

Comment: This might be of interest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds(v=vs.110).aspx (note there is a corresponding version that returns milliseconds, and methods that operate in the opposite direction)

Comment: @Patricia: You appear to have been offended by my suggestion for improving the readability of your code.  For that, I apologize.  Please realize that my suggestions were offered in the spirit of making your code more readable and more maintainable.  However, please also realize that should you ever check in code that looks like "var milliseconds = something.TotalSeconds;", you (or someone else) will likely have a problem sometime in the future,  This isn't meant as a "criticism", just as a suggestion for improvement.
I am impressed though - no one has ever called me a bully before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fundamental problem with the way you're handling dates here, and if I boil it down to one thing, I think the problem is that `ToUniversalTime()` doesn't work the way you think it does.

What `ToUniversalTime()` does is, simply giving the `UTC` time of a time that's defined in a different time zone. For example, say my local time is `UTC-7`. So if I define a `DateTime` object *without specifying `DateTimeKind`* and set the value to, say, `2017/6/1  9:00:00`, that means, at that time the actual `UTC` time is `2017/6/1 16:00:00` at that time, and `ToUniversalTime()` will give you a `DateTime` object with that value.

Let me change your `ToUTCString()` method a little bit and show you the problem with it. It's returning a `long` value instead of `string` now, and I break down the first line of code into two.

```
public static long ToUTC(this DateTime _input)
{
    var utcTime = _input.ToUniversalTime();
    var totalSeconds = utcTime.Subtract(UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
    return Convert.ToInt64(totalSeconds);
}
```

And notice that in your `Extensions` class, the `UnixEpoch` object's `DateTimeKind` is set to `UTC`. I changed the date to `2017/6/1 8:00:00` for the ease of understanding.

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static DateTime ToDateTime(this Int64 _input)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(_input);
}
```

Now let's call that method with a `DateTime` object whose `DateTimeKind` is set to `UTC`.

```
// dateObj will have time 2017/6/1 9:00:00 _in UTC_.
var dateObj = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
// This method converts to UTC, but it's already in UTC, so no actual conversion takes place.
// Then subtracts UnixEpoch from it, which is also in UTC. 
long dateInLong = dateObj.ToUTC();
// The difference is one hour, so dateInLong will be 3600.
Console.WriteLine(dateInLong);
// This method adds the above difference to UnixEpoch, and displays the time.
Console.WriteLine(dateInLong.ToDateTime());
```

Now, here, everything is in `UTC` and you should see output as expected, like below:

> 3600
>
> 6/1/2017 09:00:00

All good so far.

Now change things a bit, and let's set our `dateObj` to local instead of `UTC`, as you do in your example.

```
// Notice that the object is in local time now.
var dateObj = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0);
long dateInLong = dateObj.ToUTC();
Console.WriteLine(dateInLong);
Console.WriteLine(dateInLong.ToDateTime());
```

Now, the above `dateObj` will have time `9:00:00`, *but in my local time*. My actual location is `UTC-7` so note that this means `9AM` local time for me is `4PM` UTC. But note that we haven't changed the `UnixEpoch` object, which is still in `UTC` and time is set to `8AM UTC` in it. And therefore, `dateInLong` will be `28,800` (8 hours x 60 mins x 60 seconds). So when your `ToDateTime()` method is called, it adds `28,000` seconds to `8AM UTC` time, and returns as a `DateTime` object, of which time now is `4PM UTC`.

> 28800
>
> 6/1/2017 16:00:00

And that's why depending on the time you set your `dateObj` to, your output *changes* time as you said.

---

### Solution

You need to decide which time zone to use, and stick to that. One option would be to get rid of all the `UTC` conversions and have all times set in local time.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // NOT set to UTC
    private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0);

    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this Int64 _input)
    {
        return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(_input);
    }

    public static long ToUTC(this DateTime _input)
    {
        // NOT converted to UTC. So... change variable names accordingly.
        var utcTime = _input;
        var totalSeconds = utcTime.Subtract(UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
        return Convert.ToInt64(totalSeconds);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Notice that the object is in local time and NOT UTC.
        var dateObj = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0);
        long dateInLong = dateObj.ToUTC();
        Console.WriteLine(dateInLong);
        Console.WriteLine(dateInLong.ToDateTime());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The other option, set EVERYTHING to UTC, but then you'll have to make sure that the `DateTime` object on which you call `ToUTC()` is defined in UTC and not local.

So:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

And

```
var utcTime = _input.ToUniversalTime();
```

And finally

```
var dateObj = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

---

### BUT...

I see a bigger problem with you code, looking at the second code snippet. In the `ForecastIORequest()` constructor, you're saving time as a `string`. And that's not an ideal solution in my opinion. Because as you found the hard way, depending on what time zone the calling object was created, your time difference will be, well, different. And you'd have no way of knowing which.

I'd rather store the `DateTime` object as it is, and read it and calculate the difference when needed, taking into account time zones.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) - there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond. Simply take `DateTime.Ticks / 10000` (ten thousand) and you have your milliseconds.

Here's a simple extension method to get the milliseconds as a long (that's Int64):

```
public static long ToMilliseconds(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.Ticks / 10000;
}
```